# Worksheet name from simplexlsx.class.php?

Tags: php

I was able to get the PHP class `simplexlsx.class.php` working but ran into problem when trying to retrieve the name of a worksheet. Does anyone know how to retrieve the name of any given using that class? I'm sure it is in there because I could see the string I wanted using `var_dump()`.

Comment: Where did you download this class from?  Did you read their docs?  What have tried?  What did `var_dump` show you?

Comment: `var_dump()` shows a bunch of raw xml codes, which would take some work to parse it out but the latest version has a function that does it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I visited the developer's page for the updates. The latest version does have the functionality.

https://github.com/TobiasBg/TablePress/blob/master/libraries/simplexlsx.class.php